# Android Studio can't Start after Installation Start Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2, android-studio-arctic-fox

After Successfully Installed Android Studio, I was unable to run Android Studio. I'm Attaching the Screenshot below...

I have tried various methods to run Android Studio but I failed!!!
Here are a few of the methods that I want to discuss with u that I've tried.

1. Open the folder where you installed Android Studio:
   **ex: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`**

Find and edit **idea.properties.** You can edit this with use notepad++ or
any similar application that allows text editing.

Add this line as the final in the file:

`disable.android.first.run=true`

2)Deleting the Existed Folder of `[AndroidStudio2020.3][2]** Present inside **C:\Users\Appdata\Local\Google`

3)Deleting the Existed Folder of **AndroidStudio2020.3** Present inside **C:\Users\Appdata\Roaming\Google**

4. I've also reinstalled the Android Studio but I'm having the same error again and again

**Error Screenshot Link:-**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMLq.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMLq.png

Comment: what is the error

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMLq.png

Comment: the setup might not download properly

Comment: it's downloaded and installed properly but i'm getting the same error,Tried a lots of methods but i failed

Comment: try to search in your laptop android and whatever is there del that or last option is reset your system bcz we cant see any error

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and install again after downloading from the website.

Comment: I have done this before but nothing happend

Comment: Try to uninstall using `IObitUninstaller` as it removes registries and completely removes software from the system.